# SQL how to obtain two columns as a result of a two where condition in one statement

Tags: sql, pivot, where-clause

I'm enrolling in a Coursera course called SQL FOR DATA SCIENCE, offered by the University of California, Davis. I'm doing the last test and there is the next question based on a table of customer reviews:

Are there more reviews with the word "love" or with the word "hate" in them?

I'm getting the response doing two separate SELECT statements and obtaining two outputs:

```
SELECT COUNT(*) AS LOVE
FROM REVIEW
WHERE TEXT LIKE '%love%';

+------+
| LOVE |
+------+
| 1780 |
+------+
    
SELECT COUNT(*) AS HATE
FROM REVIEW
WHERE TEXT LIKE '%hate%';

+------+
| HATE |
+------+
|  232 |
+------+
```

Is there a way to obtain an output like this with a single statement:

```
+------+------+
| LOVE | HATE |
+------+------+
| 1780 |  232 |
+------+------+
```

I´m fairly new to SQL and though I got the response I would like to achieve in a better way. Any suggestion?

Comment: You can use a count with a case statement for this type of scenario.

Comment: Tag your question with the database you are using.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use conditional `CASE..WHEN` expression with aggregation :

```
SELECT SUM(CASE WHEN TEXT LIKE '%love%' THEN 1 END) AS LOVE,
       SUM(CASE WHEN TEXT LIKE '%hate%' THEN 1 END) AS HATE 
  FROM REVIEW
```

<kbd>[Demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=ecacfcb4b15abb65f75756b0de0e1ba1)</kbd>

Comment: thank you, your response is what I needed, the only part that I don't understand is the '1' after THEN

Comment: You're welcome @DavidLópez . The counting is incrementing by one, and I'm summing up all increments here. You can also replace SUM with COUNT in this case, but it's a good habit using SUM rather than COUNT for most of the cases.